# Digital filter. Why do these two methods produce such different results?

Tags: signal-processing

I am trying to produce a transfer function with a peak=3000 and gain=1
first order on the high pass side and second order on the low pass side.

I believe the below two methods should produce approximately the same function, but they do not.
Why are they different?
The impulse response of both are wrong in different ways.

```
anfa[cf_] := 
  TransferFunctionModel[((Power[cf, 2]/cf) + Power[cf, 0.999])*(
    s + (cf - Power[cf, 0.999]))/((s + cf) (s + cf)), s, 
   SamplingPeriod -> 1/44000];
tt = Table[{f, Abs[anfa[3000][I f]][[1, 1]]}, {f, 
    PowerRange[20, 22000, 1.1]}];
ListLogLinearPlot[tt, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
zfm[cf_] := 
  ToDiscreteTimeModel[
   TransferFunctionModel[((Power[cf, 2]/cf) + Power[cf, 0.999])*(
     s + (cf - Power[cf, 0.999]))/((s + cf) (s + cf)), s], 1/44000, 
   Method -> {"BilinearTransform"}];
tt = Table[{f, Abs[zfm[3000][I f]][[1, 1]]}, {f, 
    PowerRange[20, 22000, 1.1]}];
ListLogLinearPlot[tt, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: belisarius, thank you for the clarifying edits.  I am new to Stack Exchange.  Will be better!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first mistake I see is that you are not using the correct expression of the complex variable for discrete-time systems (it is $e^{i f T}$ not $i f$ as for continuous-time systems).

```
anfa[cf_] := TransferFunctionModel[((Power[cf, 2]/cf) + 
  Power[cf, 
   0.999])*(s + (cf - Power[cf, 0.999]))/((s + cf) (s + cf)), s, 
SamplingPeriod -> 1/44000];
tt = Table[{f, Abs[anfa[3000][Exp[I f/44000]]][[1, 1]]}, {f, 
PowerRange[20, 22000, 1.1]}];
ListLogLinearPlot[tt, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I am not quite sure what you are comparing it with. The natural thing would be to compare it with an equivalent continuous-time system.

```
zfm[cf_] := ToContinuousTimeModel[
TransferFunctionModel[((Power[cf, 2]/cf) + 
   Power[cf, 0.999])*(s + (cf - Power[cf, 0.999]))/((s + cf) 
(s +    cf)), s, SamplingPeriod -> 1/44000], Method-> {"BilinearTransform"}];
tt = Table[{f, Abs[zfm[3000][I f]][[1, 1]]}, {f, 
PowerRange[20, 22000, 1.1]}];
ListLogLinearPlot[tt, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The comparison can be done more cleanly using the built-in `BodePlot`.

```
BodePlot[{anfa[3000], ToContinuousTimeModel[anfa[3000]]}, {130, 10^4}, 
PlotLayout -> "Magnitude", ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Absolute"}]
```

[image]

Comment: That solved it!  Thank you.